# Type error: Cannot read property 'lng' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, react-fullstack

**This is the code where i get that error:**

```
export const showDataOnMap =(data, casesType = 'cases') => (
    data.map(country => (
        <Circle
            center={[country.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.lng]}
            fillOpacity={0.4}
            color={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
            radius={
                Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
            }
        >
            <Popup>
                <h1>Im a popup</h1>
            </Popup>
        </Circle>
    ))
);
```

Please Help with this error...

Comment: Seems like one of objects missing countryInfo property, can't help without knowing data, please update question to include data.

Comment: How do you receive `data`?